# I have 1 error popping up but When I try to run the app it says I have all of these other errors that are wrong

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkluy.png)

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/app/sign_in/home_page.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/app/sign_in/sign_in_page.dart';
import 'package:time_trackerpractice/services/auth.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPage({Key key, this.auth}) : super(key: key);
  final AuthBase auth;

  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}


class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {

  User _user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    _updateUser(widget.auth.currentUser);
  }


  void _updateUser(User user) {
    setState(() {
      _user = user;
    });
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamBuilder<User>(
     stream: widget.auth.authStateChanges(),
     builder: (context,snapshot){
     if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){
       final User user =snapshot.data;
       if(user == null){
         return SignInPage(
           auth: widget.auth,
           onSignIn: _updateUser,
         );
       }
       return HomePage(
           auth: widget.auth,
           onSignOut: => _updateUser(null),
       );
     }

       return Scaffold(
       body:Center(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
       );
       );

     },
   );
```

I have been following a flutter course and on the code that I typed up for the app I am  having 1 error popping up but When I try to run the app it says I have all of these other errors that are wrong.This is the only thing that comes up as an error and the semicolon  `onSignOut: => _updateUser(null)`,under it so I don't know were I went wrong.but these are the errors that pop up below:

```
lib/app/sign_in/landing_page.dart:38:38: Error: Can't find '}' to match '{'.
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                                   ^
lib/app/sign_in/landing_page.dart:16:52: Error: Can't find '}' to match '{'.
class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
                                                   ^
lib/app/sign_in/landing_page.dart:52:23: Error: Expected an identifier, but got '=>'.
Try inserting an identifier before '=>'.
       onSignOut: => _updateUser(null),
                  ^^
lib/app/sign_in/landing_page.dart:52:26: Error: Expected ',' before this.
       onSignOut: => _updateUser(null),
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/app/sign_in/landing_page.dart:52:26: Error: Place positional arguments before named arguments.
Try moving the positional argument before the named arguments, or add a name to the argument.
       onSignOut: => _updateUser(null),
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/app/sign_in/landing_page.dart:52:26: Error: Expected named argument.
           onSignOut: => _updateUser(null),
                         ^
lib/app/sign_in/landing_page.dart:50:23: Error: No named parameter with the name '#2'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors, one is that you did not close the methods, add this line at the end of your code:

```
}}
```

It should look like this:

```
 ...
 return Scaffold(
       body:Center(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
       );
       );

     },
   );
 }}
```

The reason why this is necessary is because you must close both build and your widget class

```
class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // some code
  } // <--- you missed this
} // <--- you also missed this one, so you must add two }} at the end of the file
```

Second error, you forgot the parenthesis on the lambda function:

From this:

```
onSignOut: => _updateUser(null),
```

to this:

```
onSignOut: () => _updateUser(null),
```

If you don't understand what a lambda is, take a look at this resource: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#anonymous-functions

Comment: Thank you for your help.I really appreciate it.It helped me out alot